# Deploying to GAE with GWT requires uploading hundreds and takes forever

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Some background: I have what I would consider a medium-sized GWT app deployed to appengine. I recently configured it to support some locales other than en_US, which has resulted in 96 permutations during GWT compilation.

I'm in the process of testing out some small changes to the app, and after compilation it's telling me its got to upload 310 files. I've been sitting here watching it for 30 minutes and there's been no progress – although I'm confident it will eventually deploy.

This is typical of my experience with GWT/Appengine: uploading hundreds of files will take a LONG time. However, now I believe with all these GWT permutations even very simple changes to the app are going to take an hour or more to deploy. That's pretty painful.

Is this expected/typical? Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything I can do make this less painful? I'm also worried about the day where we break something and need to fix it and the quickest we'll be able to turn it around is an hour.

Comment: How many locales do you have? How long does it take to compile your app? Do you deploy from Eclipse?

Comment: Just en, es, and fr. The amount of time it takes to do the GWT compilation is not an issue (for now – maybe after I add more locales it will). The problem is that small-ish changes can result in lots of files needing to be uploaded and then that takes a long time (30min-hour).

Comment: How do you get 96 permutations with 3 locales? You should have 24.

Comment: There's other things in the module that require permutations. For example, the same app several different variations for mobile browsers. But now I'm thinking I should just break off the mobile stuff into its own app.

Comment: You have 24 permutations per locale, if which 8 are "standard" GWT permutations. Do you really have 16 mobile flavors? If not, then something is wrong. If you reduce the number of permutations, it will automatically reduce your deploy time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deploy from your IDE, try uploading files using appcfg. In my experience, it works much faster:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Uploading_the_App

By the way, I have a large app, and I never had a deploy over 10 minutes even during the busy hours (deploys work much faster at night and on weekends). And when you do a small fix, you should have only a few files changed - not hundreds.

Comment: I do occasionally use appcfg and it does seem a little faster, but only a little. If it was twice as fast I'd never deploy from my IDE.